# Fastest way to calculate a point between minima and maxima

Tags: algorithm, search, math, optimization

I have a list of sorted elements. They form a structure like a sinusoidal wave. I am interested in finding a point between Maxima and Minima - In a fastest manner.

At present, I have tried binary search and Fibonacci search. They both give approximately same time. But I think I am spending to much time in searching for this elements. Thorough the literature, is there a faster way? I am not worried about space complexity.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge on the distribution of your values, i.e. is it smooth or it's possible that there exist dense/sparse areas?

Comment: distribution can not be constant. Sometimes its very smooth, at other times Maxima and Minima might lie next to each other. The case where they are very close might be rare, say once in 256 iterations.

Comment: Are you using a cache efficient layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, binary search is the lowest bound for searching in sorted lists and runs in `O(log(n))`. Till our days, the only way you can beat it, in non-quantum computing, is to have some knowledge on the distribution of your data.

However, if the distribution is uniform enough, you can actually use [Interpolation Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search), where the performance can be shown to be `O(log(log(N)))` on average.

In your case, where you have to search in-a-range and not a single value, Interpolation Search may perform really well if your values have a uniform distribution and your min-max window is big enough; you may be very close from your first hits.

*Another solution would be to keep some kind of cache from previous queries, so you don't search the whole list on successive requests of the same range.